# Why do I have NullPointerException in my sort implementation?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on my assignment and I am suppose to create a sort method for my array. However, I'm getting a null pointer error in my sort method and I'm not sure why. This is my code below.

```
public Object[] sorted() {
    getSetArray();
    Arrays.sort(setArray);
    return setArray;
}
```

> these are my line of error java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232) at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176) at
>   java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146) at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472) at
>   setadt.SetADT.sorted(SetADT.java:280) at
>   setadt.SetADTDriver_sol.main(SetADTDriver_sol.java:233)

```
package setadt;
import java.util.*;



public class SetADT {

    private static Random rand = new Random();
    private final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;
    private final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    private int size;
    private Object[] setArray;

    public SetADT() {
        size = 0;
        setArray = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    public SetADT(int capacity) {
        size = 0;
        setArray = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void add(Object newElement) {

        if (size() == setArray.length) {
            resize();
        }
        if(!contains(newElement) == true){
           setArray[size] = newElement;
         size++;   
        }
        //System.out.println(newElement +"\t" + size);
    }

    public void addAll(SetADT set) {

        Object[] temp = set.getSetArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
            if (!this.containsValue(temp[i])) {
                add(temp[i]);
            }
        }
    }
   public boolean contains(Object element) {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (setArray[i].equals(element)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean containsValue(Object element) {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (setArray[i].toString().equals(element.toString())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(SetADT set) {

        boolean result = false;
        Object element;

        if (size() == set.size()) {
            result = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                element = setArray[i];
                if (!set.contains(element)) {
                    return false;

                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        if (size == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Object remove(Object element) {

        Object result = new Integer(NOT_FOUND);
        int search = NOT_FOUND;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size() && search == NOT_FOUND; i++) {
                if (setArray[i].equals(element)) {
                    search = i;
                }
            }

            if (search != NOT_FOUND) {

                result = setArray[search];

                setArray[search] = setArray[size - 1];
                setArray[size - 1] = null;
                size--;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    public Object removeRandom() {
        int element;
        Object value = new Integer(NOT_FOUND);

        if (!isEmpty()) {

            element = rand.nextInt(size);
            value = setArray[element];

            setArray[element] = setArray[size - 1];
            setArray[size - 1] = null;
            size--;
        }

        return value;
    }
    public int size() {

        return size;
    }
    public SetADT union(SetADT set) {

        SetADT newSet = new SetADT();

        newSet.addAll(this);
        newSet.addAll(set);

        return newSet;
    }

    private void resize() {

        Object[] newArray = new Object[setArray.length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < setArray.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = setArray[i];
        }

        setArray = newArray;
    }

    public Object[] getSetArray() {

        return setArray;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            if ((i % 10) == 0 && i != 0) {
                result += "\n";
            } 

            result = result + setArray[i].toString() + "\t";
        }
        return result;
    }

    public SetADT intersection(SetADT set) {

        SetADT newSet = new SetADT(); 
        for(int index = 0; index < set.size; index++){
            if(set.contains(set) == set.contains(setArray)){
                newSet.add(set);
            }   
        }
        return newSet;
    }

    public SetADT difference(SetADT set) {

        SetADT newSet = new SetADT();
        for(int index = 0; index < set.size; index++){
            if(set.contains(set) == false){

                newSet.add(set);
            }
        }
        return newSet;
    }

    public Object[] sorted() {
        setArray = getSetArray();
        Arrays.sort(setArray);
        return setArray;
    }

    public static String getObjectArray(Object[] o) {
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            s += (o[i] + " ");
        }
        return s;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `setArray` and what's the purpose of the call to `getSetArray()`?

Comment: what line are you getting the NPE on?

Comment: these are my line of error

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:232)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:176)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at setadt.SetADT.sorted(SetADT.java:280)
    at setadt.SetADTDriver_sol.main(SetADTDriver_sol.java:233)

Comment: What version of Java are you on? Line 232 in `ComparableTimSort.java` for me is in the middle of a javadoc comment...

Comment: I'm not quite sure my teacher told me to download the program called "netbeans" on verious 7.2

Comment: That's an IDE, not your Java version... What happens if you open up a command prompt and type in "java -version"?

Comment: not sure if it helps but I posted my whole code

Comment: when i type in "java- version" in cmd it says 
"unrecongnized option"
"Error:could not creat the java virtual machine."
"Error: a fatal expetion has occurred. program will exit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of NPE is that you store null in your array. The implementation of [ComparableTimSort](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/src/share/classes/java/util/ComparableTimSort.java.html) does not check for null.

```
 private static void binarySort(Object[] a, int lo, int hi, int start) {
 214         assert lo <= start && start <= hi;
 215         if (start == lo)
 216             start++;
 217         for ( ; start < hi; start++) {
 218             @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 219             Comparable<Object> pivot = (Comparable) a[start];
 220 
 221             // Set left (and right) to the index where a[start] (pivot) belongs
 222             int left = lo;
 223             int right = start;
 224             assert left <= right;
 225             /*
 226              * Invariants:
 227              *   pivot >= all in [lo, left).
 228              *   pivot <  all in [right, start).
 229              */
 230             while (left < right) {
 231                 int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
 232                 if (pivot.compareTo(a[mid]) < 0)
 233                     right = mid;
 234                 else
 235                     left = mid + 1;
 236             }
 237             assert left == right;
 238
```

You must assure that null value is not stored in your array.

To do that you must assert that argument passed in method `add` is not null and create a copy of your container before sorting to valid size.

```
public Object[] sorted() {

    Object[] toSort = Arrays.copyOf(getSetArray(),getSize());
    Arrays.sort(toSort);
    return toSort;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers (at this point in time) are correct in that none of the elements of your array/list should be `null`, however, the explanations given are only suggestive.  This is because the contracts of the JDK's collection sort methods don't directly address `null` elements except to say:

- From `Collections.sort()`: *All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface.*
- From `List.sort()`: *All elements in this list must be mutually comparable using the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).*
- From `Arrays.sort()`: *All elements in the array must be mutually comparable by the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the array).*

From simple interpretation of the contracts of these sort methods, `null` indeed does not implement `Comparable` nor is it going to be safe during a cast.  **Indirectly speaking, you can't have `null` in your sortable collection.**

If you can change the contract on your collection to disallow `null` elements, then you're done.

However, that doesn't resolve the **glaring contract requirement in `java.lang.Comparable`**:

> *Note that null is not an instance of any class, and e.compareTo(null) should throw a NullPointerException even though e.equals(null) returns false.*

This requires code in your `Comparable` implementation to handle a `null` argument.

If you've gotten here because your test code didn't throw the right `NullPointerException` when attempting to sort your test list with a `null` element, you're testing the wrong thing.  But there's tradeoffs even after testing the right thing.

`java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending()` assumes element 1 is not `null`.  If it is, you get the unexpected NPE - but not the one you were expecting from your `Comparable` implementation.

**The Fix**

Maybe you're here because you're trying to get 100% test coverage on your method that sorts a collection.  The Collection Framework's sort methods won't accept `null` in your collection even though they don't directly speak to it, but your `Comparable` implementation must still handle a `null`.

You must instead test your Comparable implementation directly with a `null` parameter.  This may require raising its visibility to *default*, i.e. package visibility and then write a test method directly against your `Comparable` implementation.

Your `Comparable.compareTo(T)` method might look something like:

```
public class ListManipulator {
    private List<Percentage> mylist;
    class Percentage implements Comparable<Percentage> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Percentage o) {
            if (o == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("null is not comparable");
            }
            if (o.percent == percent) {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (this.percent < o.percent) {
                return -1;
            }
            else return 1;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You'll need test code similar to:

```
    try {
        cut = new ListManipulator();
        cut.new Percentage(10).compareTo(null);
        fail("should have thrown a NullPointerException: cannot have a null value");
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        assertThat(e.getMessage(), is(notNullValue()));
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The drawback here is possibly needing to raise the visibility of your `Comparable` implementation.  At the end of the day, it gets the test coverage you wanted.

However, if you don't want to raise the visibility of your `Comparable` because your code is highly cohesive and not coupled (nice work!) then decide if you can live with less than 100% test coverage.

An ugly alternative places a `null` in a test list at position `0` and a valid element at position `1`.  Sorting that will produce the NPE you were looking for but at the expense of writing test code coupled to implementation details in the JDK.  **Don't do this.**

**Bottom Line**

Ideally, you should be directly testing your `Comparable` implementation to verify your null handling code, as shown above.  If you're in the practice of disabling the JVM's visibility restrictions when your test cases run, then you won't need to raise the visibility of your `Comparable` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See if any elements of `setArray` are null. `Arrays.sort()` requires that each element of the array being sorted has to be non-null: ["All elements in the array must implement the Comparable interface."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)