# Sorting an array of objects? user input and comparator

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

> Trying to sort an array of objects by overallVisits from greatest to smallest but get an error. The goal is to pass in website objects to the array        then have them sorted out according to greatest overall visit to least visit.
>   I get the following error:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.ComparableTimSort.binarySort(ComparableTimSort.java:258)
>       at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:185)
>       at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1246)
>       at Project1.main(Project1.java:32)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Project1
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Website [] websites = new Website[20];

String temp;
String temp2;
int days = 4;    

 for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
 {
      System.out.println("Enter the URL of the Website:");
      temp = input.nextLine();
      websites[i] = new Website();
      websites[i].setUrl(temp);

      System.out.println("Enter the name of the Website:");
      temp2 = input.nextLine();
      websites[i].setName(temp2);

  }

 Arrays.sort(websites);

 for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
 {
      System.out.println("URL:" + websites[i].getUrl()+ " Current Visits:" +      websites[i].getCurvisit() + " Overall Visits:" + websites[i].getOvrvisit());

      System.out.println("Name of Website:" + websites[i].getName());

 }

}
}
//Class 2:
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;

 public class Website implements Comparable <Website>
{
 private String url;
 private String name;
 private int currentVisit;
 private int overallVisit;

 public Website()
 {
   this.url = url;
   this.name = name;
   this.currentVisit = getRandom1();
   this.overallVisit = getRandom2();

 }

 public String getUrl()
 {
  return url;
 }

 public void setUrl(String s)
{
  url = s;
}  

public String getName()
{
  return name;
}

public void setName(String n)
{
  name = n;
}  

public int getRandom1()
{
 Random rand = new Random();

 int num = rand.nextInt(4);
 return num;
} 

 public int getRandom2()
{
 Random rand = new Random();

 int num2 = 10 + rand.nextInt(11);
 return num2;
}

public int getCurvisit()
{
 return currentVisit;
}

public int getOvrvisit()
{
  return overallVisit;
}

public int compareTo(Website compareVisit)
{
  int compareAll = ((Website) compareVisit).getOvrvisit();
  return compareAll - this.overallVisit;
}
}
```

Comment: Unkess you need a `Website` object elsewhere, you could simply use a TreeMap and define the comparator for visits, and let the DataSet take care of the work for you. It even works dynamically. Otherwise, have `Website` implement `Comparable`, and define an appropriate `compareTo` method, and do what you're doing. Let me know if you'd like a simple example.

Comment: I've edited the question, it was missing my other class. It seems that my compare to method is not working somehow. If you can show and example or point me in the right direction some way it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: two mistakes in your code
step 1: in constructor change 20 to 10 or change loop to 20.

The cause of NPE is that you store null in your array. The implementation of ComparableTimSort does not check for null.
refernce: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796951/why-do-i-have-nullpointerexception-in-my-sort-implementation

Website [] websites = new Website[20];
changed to 
Website [] websites = new Website[10];

step 2:
eventhough you have mention about overallVisits,You haven't set its values in loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` because you have allocated 20 elements in your array but have only filled it with 10.

New Array

```
Website [] websites = new Website[20];
```

Filling the array

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: Im have got to pick 10 from a list text file of 20 different websites and randomly give them visits.The range of values for the initial visits are 0-3 for current day, and 10-20 overall. When the program starts, display the websites with all relevant information sorted according to popularity (the website with most overall visits is the most popular). Since the number of visits are random, for each run of the program, the output should be different.